# $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] gerando 2 vezes

Tags: php, html

estou com uma dificuldade.

Estou no **localhost** e quero pegar o **path** do **site** para prenecher um **link** de uma **imagem**

```
$uri = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/mvc_crud_pdo'; 

$iconeTransporte = $produtos->getTransporte() == 'Correios' 
          ?'<img src ="' . $uri . '/imgs/iconeCorreiosCaminhao.png" style="height:45px;" title="Correios" />' 
          :<img src ="' . $uri . '/imgs/iconeTransportadoraCaminhao.png" style="height:45px;" title="Transportadora" />';
```

**mvc_crud_pdo** é o **domínio**.

Algo como:

```
http://localhost/mvc_crud_pdo
```

Mas está ocorrendo o seguinte **problema**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que em **Elements**, o **link** é gerado corretamente mas no **console** dá **erro**:

O que devo fazer para corrigir essa duplicidade?

Comment: Perceba que a URL que você quer gerar, como bem citou, possui o `http://`, mas no seu código em nenhum momento isso é adicionado ao valor. Pesquise sobre a diferença de URL relativa para URL absoluta e entenderá o problema.

Comment: Obrigado, entendi! Era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço isso da seguinte forma:

- Crio um arquivo chamado Constantes.php:

Nesse arquivo guardo todos os caminhos da minha aplicação como no exemplo:

```
// Diretório absoluto do servidor / htdocs ou www/html.
define("docRoot", $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

// Caminho relativo da aplicação:
define("docProject", "/MeuApp");

// Caminho aboluto da plicação:
define("docRootProject", (docRoot . "/MeuApp"));

// Caminho relativo da pasta imagens.
define("docImagens", (docProject . "/imgs"));

// Caminho absoluto da pasta imagens.
define("docRootImagens", (docRootProject . "/imgs"));
```

E assim por diante para todas as pastas utilizadas na aplicação.

Para utilização ficaria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$iconeTransporte = ($produtos->getTransporte() == 'Correios')
? '<img src ="' . docImagens . '/iconeCorreiosCaminhao.png." style="height:45px;" title="Correios" />'
: '<img src = "' . docImagens . '/iconeTransportadoraCaminhao.png" style = "height:45px;" title = "Transportadora" />';
```

- Os "docPasta" são para links;
- Os "docRootPasta" são para requires e includes.